# EF Core vs EF6 in terms of query complexity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to ask the Entity Framework Core team what their ambition is for the scope/complexity of query translation compared to EF6.

I've used EF6 extensively and I know that if you can express it in LINQ and don't use any untranslatable functions, EF can probably translate the query correctly.

Will Entity Framework's translation be eventually as good as that, or is that something that is considered secondary, like the lazy loading feature.

If so, about what is the team eventually aiming at compare to EF6?

There's a [ticket discussing `GroupBy`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341) that appears to indicate they deem grouping an advanced type of query, but compared to what EF6 can translate, a normal group-by is pretty average.

(I'm asking here as the EF Core team says on it's site it is monitoring SO for questions.)

Comment: GroupBy Translation is scheduled for EF Core 2.1 (see roadmap  on https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We took a very different approach in EF Core. Every LINQ query should work--even if you use untranslatable functions. We do this by translating the parts of the query we can into SQL and processing the rest on the client after the results are returned by the server. As EF Core evolves, we'll translate more and more of the query into SQL (e.g. `GROUP BY`) which can make it more efficient.

In theory, our goal is to translate everything that the store supports. In some cases however (especially on NoSQL stores) there simply is no translation for a LINQ operator, and we feel it's better to be functional and inefficient than to throw.

If you want to ensure your whole query is translated, you can disable client evaluation. This will cause it to throw like EF6.

Comment: So if I interpret "In theory, our goal is to translate everything that the store supports." correctly, you goal is to be eventually indeed as good as EF6 in terms of translation, correct?

Comment: Yes. But pragmatically, resources are finite, and we'll eventually reach the point of diminishing returns. ;-)

Comment: As you can see in this blog entry: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#ef-core-20, `GROUP BY` will be supported when 2.1 is released, as it's already implemented.

Comment: I've been astonished at how little the MSSQL provider in EF Core can translate to SQL. I mean... given the legacy of Linq2Sql and EF6 that were VERY good at translating things to SQL and the fact that EF Core is at a 2.0 release, it should be miles better than it is....

How the heck do you "disable client evaluation"? I would MUCH rather be told during development (when my tables are small) that the queries are garbage vs in production after the tables have grown and the the queries start timing out or the client runs out of memory.

Comment: Found how to disable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#disabling-client-evaluation

Comment: @RonnieOverby please [submit issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new) for the things you'd like to see translated. We do [our best to prioritize](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/release-planning-process) work.